# Unity Layer-Based Collision not working for child objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collider

I have a project in unity where I have the following setup:

- a base object set in the "Ghost" layer, with a NavMeshAgent component (for collider) and a ridigbody (kinematic)

  [image: ghost object overview]
- a child object meant to "detect" players, in the layer "PlayerDetector", with a trigger collider

  [image: collider object overview]

  (this is just one example, this happens for multiple "tracker" type children objects)

I've tested, and as long as the base object has a rigidbody, the child objects collides with all layers instead of just the player one

[image: layer collisions]

Any idea why this is or how I can fix it in a somewhat clean manner?

The code for when the detection enters:

```cs
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.tag == PLAYER_TAG) //this is the issue -> this should not be requried, because it should only collide with the player layer to begin with
        {
            //Debug.Log("ADDED PLAYER: " + playersInRadius);
            playersInRadius.Add(other.gameObject);
        }
    }
```

Comment: well yuour playerdetection thing only can work with 1 thing, you also set it as trigger. You havent shared your code or details of what specifically isnt working

Comment: The point is to work with only 1 thing (if you meant the layer).
I want the "collisions" to happen for only that specific layers. The code is virually irrelevant, since what happens in the OnTriggerEnter is not important to the issue as far as I am aware, but i will add it too.

Comment: The collision matrix image is cut off to where no labels are visible.  Can you please update the image to include the full matrix or the relevant portion (including name labels).

Comment: I've added it, although I only put the image to show that only 1 layer is selected for collision (and i didn't forget that part of the setup), I don't know if the update will help much